# How to evaluate json response data - ajax form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I don't know how to write a proper question. But please let me explain this. I sent from with ajax and return with json. Each json value contain its status. So I need to test/evaluate the status and do something with it.

**JSON**

```
{url:"error",email:"ok",name:"ok"}
```

**JS**

```
//new port
$('#pflBtn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'inc/wcont8_port_db.php',
        data :$(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.url=="err"){//if url=error
                $('#plf_url').addClass('error');//will add .error into #plf_url class
            }else{
                $('#plf_url').addClass('success');
            }
        }
    })//ajax
})
```

**html**

```
<form class="pflForm">
    <div class="form-group form-float">         
        <div class="form-line" id="pfl_url">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pfl_url" value="URL" required />
            <label class="form-label">URL (www.domain.com)</label>
        </div>
    </div><!-- form-group form-float -->
<button type="submit" id="pflBtn">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Do you have a specific issue with the code? Your description only says what it does. Although note that `data.url == 'err'` should be `data.url == 'error'` given your object.

Comment: Shouldn't JSON names be in double quotes?

Comment: @yezzz yep, although that looks like the deserialised object resulting from the JSON response, which does not need the keys to be quoted

Comment: Thanks every effort here, I solved this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes you have made, check my comments with the code and try again by changing them:

```
$('#pflBtn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'inc/wcont8_port_db.php',
        data :$(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.url=="error"){// url has value 'error', but this was checking 'err'
                $('#plf_url').addClass('error');//will add .error into #plf_url class but the class is not available in your html,
            }else{
                $('#plf_url').addClass('success');
            }
        }
    })//ajax
})
```

Comment: I hope when the data.url="error" it will add the line <div class="form-line" id="pfl_url"> with class .error inside.